# How to loop through two Sass maps?

Tags: css, sass

I have two sass maps.

```
$map-one: (
 name1: value1,
 name2: value2,
 name3: value3,
 name4: value4,
);

$map-two: (
 name5: value5,
 name6: value6,
);
```

I created an each loop to generate a class with the name as the class name holding the value as the content.

```
@each $name, $value in $map-one {
 .#{$name} {
  content: $value;
 }
}
```

Now the above is for only one map. But I want to do the same for `map-two`. Is there a way to add that to the same loop above without creating another loop?

Something like:

```
@each $name, $value in $map-one and $name2, $value2 in $map-two {
 .#{$name} {
  content: $value;
 }

 .#{$name2} {
  content: $value2;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both maps has same structure then you should use a single map only, but if you want to use both then use [map-merge()](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map_merge-instance_method) like,

```
$map-one: (
   name1: value1,
   name2: value2,
   name3: value3,
   name4: value4,
);

$map-two: (
   name5: value5,
   name6: value6,
);

$merged: map-merge($map-one, $map-two);
@each $name, $value in $merged {
   .#{$name} {
       content: $value;
    }
}
```